# Insert values from DataGridView to MySql-Database during runtime

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

I got a problem with my DataGridview: I can save some value in my MySql-Database by pressing a button with the following code:

**Code**

```
   private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123";
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

        try
        {
            string sql = "select *from test.edata ;";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);
            MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;

            MySqlCommand insertCmd =cb.GetInsertCommand().Clone();
            insertCmd.CommandText = insertCmd.CommandText +";SELECT last_insert_id() AS id";
            insertCmd.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.FirstReturnedRecord;
            da.InsertCommand = insertCmd;
            cb.DataAdapter = null;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Familienname"] = "Mustermann";
            row["Eid"] = "1";
            row["Vorname"] = "Max";
            row["age"] = "20";
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            da.Update(dt);

            conn.Close();




        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

**Question**: Can I save the full DataGridView in my Database whenever the form is closing, or whenever I press a Button? I don´t want to insert the values with my code. The values should be read out of the Cells. So the user can change something on the UI and if he close the Form the Gridview will be saved in the MySql-Database.

I know this website is not a "code it for me" Site, but I´m sure there is a method which can Insert all values in my MySql-Database!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**  I found this link: [MysqlLINK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldataadapter.html) But the sample programm still don´t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I nearly solved the problem:

**Code**

> ```
>     private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>     {
>         string id = dt.Rows[e.RowIndex]["Eid"] + "";
>         string col = dt.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ColumnName;
>         string data = dgv1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value + "";
> ```

```
        string sql = string.Format("UPDATE `test`.`edata` SET `{0}` = '{1}' WHERE Eid = {2};", col, data, id);

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

> ```
>     private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         dt = new DataTable();
> ```

```
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "select *from test.edata ;";
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

        dgv1 = new DataGridView();
        dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = true;
        dgv1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellEndEdit);
        dgv1.CellValidating += new DataGridViewCellValidatingEventHandler(dgv_CellValidating);
        dgv1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        dgv1.DataSource = dt;
        this.Controls.Add(dgv1);
    }
}


    private void dgv_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            dgv1.CancelEdit();
        }
    }
```

I´m really sorry for this question! May it help an other guy! Thank you all for your time! I won´t delete this descussion with myself! :) I hope someone will give a good rating to this answer. Anyway thank you if you tried to solve this problem and have a nice day! :)